# Getting a substring from a string based on some prefix

Tags: javascript

I have the below string response which I am storing in a variable.

```
TotalHTTP/1.1 200 OK,Cache-Control: max-age=900, public,Connection: keep-alive,Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 06:54:04 GMT,Content-Length: 28359,Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8,a:b,
```

I want to extract a particular string`s response and store it in a separate variable to print.

For example.. What should I do if I have to extract Cache-Control`s response - **max-age=900, public**

Tried with split, indexof and few other methods and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex match:

```
var Response = "TotalHTTP/1.1 200 OK,Cache-Control: max-age=900, public,Connection: keep-alive,Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 06:54:04 GMT,Content-Length: 28359,Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8,a:b,",
    CacheControlRegEx = /Cache-Control:\s(.+?),/,
    CacheControl = false;

if (CacheControl = CacheControlRegEx.exec(Response)){
    CacheControl = CacheControl[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was my requirement!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Works fine with split function, with the below code.

```
var response = "TotalHTTP/1.1 200 OK,Cache-Control: max-age=900, public,Connection: keep-alive,Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 06:54:04 GMT,Content-Length: 28359,Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8,a:b,";
var splitted = response.split(",");
var cache_splitted = splitted[1].split(":");
var cache_val = cache_splitted[1];
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4x1krny/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use multiple splits:

```
var string = "TotalHTTP/1.1 200 OK,Cache-Control: max-age=900, public,Connection: keep-alive,Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 06:54:04 GMT,Content-Length: 28359,Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8,a:b,";
var all = {};
/* First split the string at the comma */
string = string.split(",");
/* Now loop through the created array */
for(var o = 0; o < string.length; o++){
    /* Splitting each element again, this time at the `:` */
    var temp = string[o].split(":");
    /* And assigning the first in the temporary element as the key
     * And then either a value or an empty string. I used .trim() to 
     * make it easier, it could be even easier if you 
     * use .toLowerCase() so you can't make typos. */
    all[temp[0].trim()] = temp[1] || "";
}
```

Now you can ask for the value of anything by doing

```
all["Cache-Control"];
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var string = "TotalHTTP/1.1 200 OK,Cache-Control: max-age=900, public,Connection: keep-alive,Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 06:54:04 GMT,Content-Length: 28359,Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8,a:b,";
  var all = {};
  /* First split the string at the comma */
  string = string.split(",");
  /* Now loop through the created array */
  for(var o = 0; o < string.length; o++){
      /* Splitting each element again, this time at the `:` */
      var temp = string[o].split(":");
      /* And assigning the first in the temporary element as the key
       * And then either a value or an empty string. I used .trim() to 
       * make it easier, it could be even easier if you 
       * use .toLowerCase() so you can't make typos. */
      all[temp[0].trim()] = temp[1] || "";
  }
  document.write("Cache-Control contains: " + all["Cache-Control"])
  </script>
```

You could technically do another split inside the temp[1] element to separate the max-age=900 so you can do more detailed things, but this will do.